# Incorrect Use Of 'IN'?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find all occurrences of a string in a field using the IN command but not returning any results when I know there should be some. 
I think the best way to show you is by example:

```
mysql> SELECT detail_sections FROM inet_staff_details WHERE detail_sections !='';
+-----------------+
| detail_sections |
+-----------------+
| 10,11           |
| 10,11           |
| 10,11           |
| 10,11           |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM inet_staff_details WHERE 11 IN (detail_sections);
Empty set, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM inet_staff_details WHERE '11' IN (detail_sections);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the number 11 is in the comma separated list but does not show up in the results. Please can you advise what I am doing wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM inet_staff_details WHERE FIND_IN_SET(10, detail_sections);
```

[FIND_IN_SET function.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 2):

What IN does, is to see if there is any value in the column (in this case `detail_sections`) which equals the specified value (in this case `11`).

You should use `LIKE` to get the values that you want. 
i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM inet_staff_details 
WHERE detail_sections LIKE '11,%'
   OR detail_sections LIKE '%,11' 
   OR detail_sections LIKE '%,11,%' 
   OR detail_sections = '11';
```

Comment: @Brian true, but it is an example. The query will have to be modified anyhow based on values, but yes i can modify the query to not pick out 113, 411, 51124, etc

Answer (score 1):

Yeah IN won't work for you here. IN is designed to pick out complete values, not substrings which is bascially what you've got here. Your problem is, that this is a basically flawed database design which makes searching for specific values such as 11 really difficult.

Your choices are

(a) redesign it a bit (read up on normalising databases, and joining tables), or

(b) search where: `detail_sections = '11' or detail_sectoins LIKE '11,%' or detail_sections LIKE '%,11,%' or detail_sections LIKE '%,11'`

Comment: Agree its not the best design. Dont know what I was thinking all those months ago, but Im on a tight schedule so a quick fix will need to do for now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM inet_staff_details 
WHERE detail_sections LIKE '%,11,%'
OR detail_sections LIKE '%,11'
OR detail_sections LIKE '11,%'
OR detail_sections = '11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
   select * from inet_staff_details 
   where instr(concat(',', detail_sections, ','), ',11,') > 0
```